# JQ format jenkins testreport json to csv

Tags: json, jq

I have the following base file (tried to make it as minimal as possible)
from Jenkins nightly testreport

```
{
  "_class" : "hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult",
  "testActions" : [
    
  ],
  "duration" : 9408.876,
  "empty" : false,
  "failCount" : 4,
  "passCount" : 147,
  "skipCount" : 1040,
  "suites" : [
    {
      "cases" : [
        {
          "testActions" : [
            
          ],
          "age" : 0,
          "className" : "Main testsuite 1",
          "duration" : 17.281,
          "errorDetails" : null,
          "errorStackTrace" : null,
          "failedSince" : 0,
          "name" : "testcase 1.1",
          "properties" : {
            
          },
          "skipped" : false,
          "skippedMessage" : null,
          "status" : "PASSED",
          "stderr" : null,
          "stdout" : null
        },
        {
          "testActions" : [
            
          ],
          "age" : 0,
          "className" : "Main testsuite 1",
          "duration" : 40.538,
          "errorDetails" : null,
          "errorStackTrace" : null,
          "failedSince" : 0,
          "name" : "testcase 1.2",
          "properties" : {
            
          },
          "skipped" : false,
          "skippedMessage" : null,
          "status" : "PASSED",
          "stderr" : null,
          "stdout" : null
        }
      ],
      "duration" : 170.714,
      "enclosingBlockNames" : [
        "Blockname 1",
        "Blockname 2"
      ],
      "enclosingBlocks" : [
        "52",
        "25"
      ],
      "id" : null,
      "name" : "Main testsuite 1",
      "nodeId" : "67",
      "properties" : {
        
      },
      "stderr" : null,
      "stdout" : null,
      "timestamp" : null
    },
      {
      "cases" : [
        {
          "testActions" : [
            
          ],
          "age" : 0,
          "className" : "Main testsuite 2",
          "duration" : 17.781,
          "errorDetails" : null,
          "errorStackTrace" : null,
          "failedSince" : 0,
          "name" : "testcase 2.1",
          "properties" : {
            
          },
          "skipped" : false,
          "skippedMessage" : null,
          "status" : "FIXED",
          "stderr" : null,
          "stdout" : null
        },
        {
          "testActions" : [
            
          ],
          "age" : 1,
          "className" : "Main testsuite 2",
          "duration" : 184.508,
          "errorDetails" : "short error message",
          "errorStackTrace" : "longer error message",
          "failedSince" : 2410,
          "name" : "testcase 2.2",
          "properties" : {
            
          },
          "skipped" : false,
          "skippedMessage" : null,
          "status" : "FAILED",
          "stderr" : null,
          "stdout" : "Random pretty long error message"
        }
      ],
      "duration" : 215.862,
      "enclosingBlockNames" : [
        "Others",
        "Blockname 2"
      ],
      "enclosingBlocks" : [
        "98",
        "25"
      ],
      "id" : null,
      "name" : "Main testsuite 2",
      "nodeId" : "113",
      "properties" : {
        
      },
      "stderr" : null,
      "stdout" : null,
      "timestamp" : null
    }
]
 
}
```

1. from this json I need to create a csv file
2. `passCount` and `failCount` in the top of the file including the values (only displayed once)
3. only testcases "cases" that have `"status": "FAILED"`
4. generally only the key/value pairs of: `className, name, errorDetail, status`

I managed to fabricate parts of my requirements but not all in one go and especially not in a csv file

That was my best attempt (I am in windows cmdline thats why the lame quotation):

```
jq "{Passed: .passCount, Failed: .failCount, Cases: .suites[].cases[]  | select((.status==\"FAILED\") or (.status==\"REGRESSION\")) | pick((.className, .errorDetails, .name, .status))}" build.json > output.json
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt(s).

Comment: @0stone0 ah jes I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix the input data first. It contains two instances of `"className" : "className" : …` which breaks JSON validity.

Iterate over the array items and construct a corresponding array, then use `@csv` and the `-r` flag to create a CSV output:

```bash
jq -r '
  [.passCount, .failCount] + (
    .suites[].cases[] | select(.status == "FAILED")
    | [.className, .name, .errorDetails, .status]
  ) | @csv
'
```

```
147,4,"Main testsuite 2","testcase 2.2","short error message","FAILED"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bc86b7QvI61)

Comment: how can I display the failCount passCount values only once when I got multiple failed testcases?

https://jqplay.org/s/boJjcg8HGMN

Comment: @QA_Chief You didn't specify a format, but try replacing the plus sign `+` with a comma `,`: https://jqplay.org/s/OtGNpZUT4vb

Comment: perfect, that does it! thanks

Comment: maybe one more follow up question: I'd like to open this directly in excel, is it possible to add 1) title line for passed, failed and 2) the keys as titles for the testcases?

Comment: @QA_Chief I don't know what Excel can or can't open. As for a CSV file, avoid mixing structures (this is what I meant earlier, better separate the two data streams). To add header rows, simply add more arrays with string items. `["passCount", "failCount"], [.passCount, .failCount] | @csv` and `["className", "name", "errorDetails", "status"], (.suites[].cases[] | …) | @csv` (or if you must: `["passCount", "failCount"], [.passCount, .failCount], [], ["className", "name", "errorDetails", "status"], (.suites[].cases[] | …) | @csv`, see https://jqplay.org/s/y5DUA_eOOwJ)

Comment: thats perfect man, exactly what I (and excel) needs, thanks for your patience and knowledge sharing!